# Error connection android and asp.net soap webservice

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, soap

i already have my web service running and this is the code (i am just first at all trying to make a log in):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Descripción breve de Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Para permitir que se llame a este servicio web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string ConectarBaseDatos()
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand())
                {

                    string connection = @"Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=sistemadatosatletasfecovol; 
                                Uid=****; Pwd=*****";
                    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connection);

                    cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cm.CommandText = "ingresarUsuario";
                    cm.Parameters.Add("_email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "asdafa@gmail.com";
                    cm.Parameters.Add("_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "*****";

                    cn.Open();
                    cm.Connection = cn;
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MySqlDataReader cr = cm.ExecuteReader();       
                    cr.Read();
                    string id;
                    id = cr["mensaje"].ToString();
                    cn.Close();
                    return id;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Its working, i actually can test it and it is fine, but when i try to connect it with andorid i get

> android java.net.connectexception failed to connect to

error.

this is my android code

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String METHOD_NAME = "ConectarBaseDatos";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ConectarBaseDatos";
String URL = "http://localhost:8080/Service1.asmx";
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);


AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

try
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    String result =  response.getProperty(0).toString();
    editText.setText(result);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    editText.setText(e.toString());
}
```

i was using this guide : http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html
and i am testing it on my own cellphone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here 
String URL = "http://localhost:8080/Service1.asmx";

use a live ip address instead of localhost for running in real device and if you want to check in emulator replace localhost with 10.0.2.2 which is the ip address of the emulator.